# Renaming links in Facebook comments

Tags: facebook

I tried to search but I couldn't find how to do it.
Is it possible to rename the links in Facebook comments so that instead of seeing `http://www.google.com`, for example, someone would see `click here`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No I don't think it's possible, nor do I think Facebook will implement it. It could lead to, many people being tricked into clicking a link. You should consider using a [link shortening/ renaming service](https://bitly.com/) such as [Bitly](https://bitly.com/).